# How to override property type on discriminated union in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have a small problem with the TS inference on discriminated unions. Let's asume I have these types:

```js
type TypeA = {
  type: 'a';
  formData: number;
  onSubmit: (data: number) => void;
};

type TypeB = {
  type: 'b';
  formData: Date;
  onSubmit: (data: Date) => void;
};

type TypeAB = TypeA | TypeB;
```

For simplicity, let's asume I have also a function, that receives a parameter typed as the discriminated union

```js
export const MyForm = (props: TypeAB) => {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // do other things

    props.onSubmit(props.formData);
  };

  return  "return does no matter"
};
```

Problem here is that TS is complaining when calling submit, because it infers that `props.formData` could not match the type expected by `onSubmit`

[image]

But according to previous types is not posible. `onSubmit` always match the type of `formData`

Also if I check for the type before calling on submit, it works without any complains

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
    // do other things
    if(props.type === 'a') props.onSubmit(props.formData);
    if(props.type === 'b') props.onSubmit(props.formData);

  };
```

However it should not be required, any ideas why TS is complaining here and how to proper define the discriminated union?

Comment: TypeScript can't deal well with *correlated unions* as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The recommended fix is to refactor to generic indexed accesses into mapped types as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The required changes for your example are shown [here]( https://tsplay.dev/mL8eam).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I see, thanks for the links, it explains the behaviour. If you write it as a response, I will accept it. The playground does not fully resolve my real scenario, because it breaks the inference. For example `if(props.type === "b") console.log(props.formData.toISOString)` should work, but it doesn't. But a different topic I guess, I can take the lead from here :)

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can only really analyze a single block of code one time.  It would be nice if TypeScript could analyze the line

```
props.onSubmit(props.formData);
```

twice, once assuming that `props` is `TypeA`, and another time assuming that it is `TypeB`.  But it doesn't.

It only looks at the type of `props.onSubmit` which is the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `((data: number) => void) | ((data: Date) => void)`, and the type of `props.formData` which is `number | Date`, and concludes (correctly) that it is not safe to call a function of the former type with an argument of the latter type. The only reason why we know that it's safe is that both of those are coming from the identical `props` object.  But TypeScript isn't tracking *identities* here, it's just looking at the *types*.

Essentially the compiler loses the *correlation* between union types `props.onSubmit` and `props.formData`.  This issue is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

And as such, the recommended fix is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which is to refactor away from unions, and instead represent things in terms of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

That will ultimately work because generics allow the compiler to analyze a single code block once for appropriately *generic* types, with the correlation between terms represented by the appearance of the generic type parameter.

The necessary refactoring for the example here is as follows.  First we create a simple mapping type from your old `key` type to the `formData` type, as a utility interface:

```
interface TypeMap {
    a: number;
    b: Date;
}
```

Then we can define `TypeA` and `TypeB` and `TypeAB` in a single *distributive object type*:

```
type TypeAB<K extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> = { [P in K]: {
    type: P;
    formData: TypeMap[P];
    onSubmit: (data: TypeMap[P]) => void;
} }[K];
```

So `TypeAB` by itself is `TypeAB<"a" | "b">` and is the equivalent to your version, and you can recover `TypeA` and `TypeB` if you want like this:

```
type TypeA = TypeAB<"a">;

type TypeB = TypeAB<"b">;
```

Now we make `MyForm` generic in that key type `K`:

```
export const MyForm = <K extends keyof TypeMap>(props: TypeAB<K>) => {
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        props.onSubmit(props.formData); // okay
    };   
    return "return does no matter"
};
```

This works because `props.onSubmit` is seen as the single function type `(data: TypeMap[K]) => void` and `props.formData` is seen as type `TypeMap[K]`, the parameter type for `props.onSubmit`.

For more details about how the refactoring works and why it's needed, see microsoft/TypeScript#47109.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUCeAHKBZBbVAb2FXNQQC5UwBXAWwCNYBuMipmgEQWnYC+wYBBxosuAIIAhADwBpVFAAe0MABMAzqgDWUTAHs4GMQSIBeXfqMncZgHypLxVAG0ACqnCp5AXRqkFKiiuDTu7EFwBjAMvBDUtviEHr4RFAZgAMp0TAwgEDQAFOp8CRJJ2CkAlE6OAG4GIOqCqAKufuwiYomSTj1yAEQIA-bsIeJi0n3lMrIDTCOdKtjREKhIGZpreJgAYtEMfQpKqlAa2nqGxuUOhdgwBtiaNDNy8vY15o6BFBtgW6gABYIDQAGyg2Vy+T6hU+3w4QXI90emgAdBlIXkIHcHk9UVEYnEEFVWKgAPRk1AGHQITAI1qdIIwKAQOgwMCoAbM1ns1DqAxQbRgAyoBh8aAwAbAASdYDqKBIUEIZnrTZrbAvMQydjYfEHInkyn0ZiwVAAH1QcSgwF1GJyWMNqEKxVKNGNLBgcNQDSaNQtzpK8R4fCgXp96iqQA)

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks for the effort you took there